# Is it possible to optimize my SQL-Request? And if yes how?

Tags: mysql

I have a problem with an MySQL-Request in my Nexuiz Statistics Webproject.
I wan't to generate statistics tables in real-time the Requests take losts of time
(With 310000 entries a request takes from 3 to 7 seconds)
Here is the SQL-Request i want to optimize, etc.

```
SELECT n.name, d.times_kill, d.times_dead, d.kd, d.times_cap, d.points
FROM
( SELECT f.player player, f.times_kill, f.times_dead, f.kd, g.times_cap, ((f.points * (7 / 3)) + POW(g.times_cap, 1.5)) points
FROM
    ( SELECT k.player player, k.times_kill, d.times_dead, (k.times_kill / d.times_dead) kd, ((k.times_kill / d.times_dead) * k.times_kill) points
    FROM
        ( SELECT player, count( * ) times_kill
        FROM `nexstat`.`dc_events`
          WHERE event = 'KILL' AND server = '2'
          GROUP BY player
          ORDER BY times_kill DESC
        ) k
        JOIN
        ( SELECT player, count( * ) times_dead
        FROM `nexstat`.`dc_events`
          WHERE event = 'DEAD' AND server = '2'
          GROUP BY player
          ORDER BY times_dead DESC
        ) d
        ON d.player = k.player
        ORDER BY points DESC
    ) f
    JOIN
    ( SELECT player, count( * ) times_cap
    FROM `nexstat`.`dc_events`
        WHERE event = 'CAP' AND server = '2'
        GROUP BY player ORDER BY times_cap DESC
    ) g
    ON f.player = g.player
) d
JOIN
( SELECT * FROM `nexstat`.`dc_players` WHERE main = 1
) n
ON d.player = n.id
GROUP BY id
ORDER BY points DESC
```

Database Model here:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `dc_events` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `timestamp` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `player` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `event` enum('CAP','KILL','DEAD','DROP','PICKUP','CHANGE','JOIN','LEAVE') NOT NULL,
  `param0` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `server` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `event` (`event`),
  KEY `server` (`server`),
  KEY `player` (`player`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 ROW_FORMAT=FIXED AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `dc_players` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `main` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `name` varchar(512) NOT NULL,
  `website` varchar(512) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(512) NOT NULL,
  `clan` varchar(512) NOT NULL,
  `country` varchar(2) NOT NULL,
  UNIQUE KEY `name` (`name`),
  KEY `website` (`website`),
  KEY `email` (`email`),
  KEY `id` (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

Would be cool if somebody helps me ;)

Comment: For these sort of questions it is *important* to include the Schema, Query Plans/Explains, and some idea of data (counts and distribution) .. make sure this information is *included in the post itself*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's probably helpful to simplify your query. Since I don't entirely understand the logic of it, I might be off somewhere. However, I think the below does essentially what your big query does, but without all the derived tables. The extra `ORDER BY` clauses will cost you a lot, as they force MySQL to go over the data repeatedly, instead of just doing it once at the end. They also don't help you answer the question as the data is just re-sorted by points in the outermost query.

```
SELECT dc_player.name AS player_name,
       times_kill,
       times_dead,
       times_cap,
       times_kill / times_dead AS kd,
       ((((times_kill / times_dead) * times_kill) * (7 / 3)) + POW(times_cap, 1.5)) AS points
FROM (
    SELECT player,
           SUM(IF(event='KILL',1,0)) AS times_kill,
           SUM(IF(event='DEAD',1,0)) AS times_dead,
           SUM(IF(event='CAP',1,0)) AS times_cap
    FROM dc_events
    GROUP BY player
) AS events
JOIN dc_player
  ON dc_player.id = events.player
ORDER BY points;
```

And why are you using MyISAM in 2012? InnoDB is now the default, and it supports more indexing options, and referential integrity (which you'll want since you have a foreign key relationship here). You'll want to have an index on dc_events.player at the very least (an InnoDB foreign key is an index by default).